# get perl to process backslash escapes in string

Tags: string, replace, eval, perl

Consider this code:

```
my $str = '"line 1\n\t line 2"'; # from some JSON, or something
say $str; # print literal backslashes, not what I want
say eval $str; # processes backslashes, but overkill
```

Is there a reasonably easy way to get the effect of the last line, but without using full-blown eval?  Even leaving aside the security implications (I mostly trust this string), this interpolates variables and stuff which I don't want.  This can be worked around by an extra preprocessing step where I manually escape dollar signs and such, but this still feels a bit too hacky, even for my tastes.

Comment: See also [String::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Escape)

Comment: This is very close to what I wanted, except... why is the good stuff never in the core?  (Well, except HTTP::Tiny.  It is in the core.  But it seems they don't want to admit it: http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-H.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mob has the right recommendation. For the general problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %unescape = map +($_ => eval "qq{\\$_}"), qw(f n r t); # etc
my $special = join '|', keys %unescape;
my $str = '"line 1\n\t line 2"';

$str =~ s{ \\ ($special) }{$unescape{$1}}xg;

print "'$str\n'";
```

Comment: That is some densely packed code!  (Well, maybe not, but I'm new to Perl.)  Let me see if I can unpack this.  On the last iteration of the loop implied by the map, $_ is the string "t", so  `"qq{\\$_}"` evaluates to `'qq{\t}'`.  Then eval turns this into a one character string containing a tab.  So we have a hash mapping the letter t to a tab character.  So far so good.  Then we join our special chars with pipe characters.  Then we do some clever regex magic to finish things off.  EDIT COMMENT: I didn't notice you changed the code; makes more sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: Good idea.  Done :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's JSON, then decode it with JSON.

```
use JSON;
my $str = '"line 1\n\t line 2"'; # from some JSON, or something
my $decoded = JSON::decode_json("[$str]");
say $decoded->[0];
```

Comment: Meh, not a core module, but possibly the right answer.  Thanks!

Comment: But JSON::PP is in core!!  Why is everything in core buried where no one can find it!